# Normalizer of normalizer of Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, sylow-theory

The question was to show that $P\in Sly_p(G)$ then $N_G(N_G(P))=N_G(P)$, where $G$ is a group. I did it using the Sylow C-theorem but was wondering if it was possible to do the problem without appealing to the C-theorem or $P$ being normal in $N_G(P)$. I did it the following way, $x\in N_G(N_G(P))$ then $xPx^{-1}\leq xN_G(P)x^{-1}=N_G(P).$Since $P,xPx^{-1}$ are Sylow p-subgroups of $N_G(P)$ then for some $y\in N_G(P)$, $xPx^{-1}=yPy^{-1}=P$.  Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to include a summary of your proof.

Comment: Added my proof.

Comment: I don't see how you could manage a proof without using $P$ being normal in $N_G(P)$, that's definitional.

Comment: I mean yes, but $P$ being normal in $N_G(P)$ gives us that it is the unique largest normal subgroup of $N_G(P)$, I wanted to avoid this proof as well.

Comment: Huh? No, it is false that $P$ normal in $N_G(P)$ implies that $P$ is the unique largest normal subgroup of $N_G(P)$. For example, the $3$-Sylow subgroup of $C_{12}$ is normal in $N_G(P)=G$, but it is not the “unique largest normal subgroup of $N_G(P)$”. What you need is that $P$ is a *$p$-Sylow subgroup* of $N_G(P)$, and being normal, it is the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N_G(P)$.

Comment: You are essentially using that $P$ is normal in $N_G(P)$. You didn’t avoid it, you just pretended to not know it and in-lined it.

Answer (score -1):

By Frattini's argument, any subgroup containing $N_{G}(P)$, where $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, is self-normalizing. For instance, $N_{G}(N_{G}(P))$.

You can find more detailed explanations in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini%27s_argument.